# Play RTSP on Mac OS X from IP Camera - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, rtsp, ip-camera

Since I spend the whole day going through Apple's Documentation and search on google how to connect and play a feed/stream through my IP camera which I can access it through the IP(can access it through my browser), I was wondering if anyone can point me to the right direction?

All the relative searches are leading me to the iOS SDK.

I have already imported AVFoundation and UIKit on my project. And I already know that the Mac OS X SDK has an attribute called AVPlayerView.

**What I am asking here is how to do the following, on an application written in Swift, for the Mac:**

```
let moviePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample_iPod", ofType: "m4v")
    if let path = moviePath {
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            if let validPlayer = playerViewController.player {
                validPlayer.play()
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously my path will be of type `let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "hhtp://10.1.xx.xx")`

- I found out that AVPlayerViewController is not on the MacOS.
- Also, I saw that lately the QTPlayer(or whatever is called) has moved into AVFoundation for the Mac

Thanks in advance..!

**This is what I have so far**

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet var avPlayerView: AVPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath("http://10.1.xx.xx"))
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    avPlayerView.player = player
    player.play()

}
```

Comment: OS X has `AVPlayerView`.

Comment: i know but it does seem to do the job. Can you help me with a sample answer just to see how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question with I have so far.

Comment: Any chance you can come back to me with a suggestion @jtbandes?